# MongoDB query through node returns a visible result, but Postgres doesn't?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, rest

I've been working with mongoDB in node using mongoose. The following query to mongoose is made when a GET request is made to a route (e.g. localhost:7000/restaurants) and displays an array full of matching objects

```js
async func() {
    return this.Restaurants.find({$or: [{city: somecity}, {postal_code: somepostalcode}]}).then(result => {
        return result;
    })
}
```

I tried a similar thing using postgres, however, calling it returns nothing on the browser, but is successfully logged onto the console:

```js
async func(){
    return await client.query(`SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE city = '${somecity}' OR postal_code = '${somepostalcode}';`, (err, res) => {
        console.log(res.rows);
        return res.rows;
    })
}
```

Why does this happen, if they both seem to return the same type of object? Is there a way to make the postgres result visible?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Not too sure about PostgreSQL but your query statement seems off ... its probably trying to query city ='somecity' or postal_code:'somepostalcode' literally.

`SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE city = '${somecity}' OR postal_code = '${somepostalcode}';`

Or follow their guide client.query(<query>,<value>,<callback>)

Comment: Oh, I copied it wrong. Thanks for the heads up! However I'm still getting the issue (result gets logged onto console, but nothing is outputted to the browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most probably because postgres API is callback based. You would need to wrap callback in promise and return query response in resolve. Updating code to something like below should help:

```
async func(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.query(`SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE city = '${somecity}' OR postal_code = '${somepostalcode}';`, (err, res) => {
      if(err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      
      return resolve(res.rows);
    })
  })
}
```